# How to use moment.JS for a certain timezone and display it in real time

Tags: javascript, timer, momentjs

How do I go about using the Moment.JS library for an international timezone and display it in real time?

This is what I have so far in my index page.

***Code:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="moment-timezone.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
    document.getElementById("time").firstChild.data = moment().format('hh:mm:ss a')
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="time">s</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my first time using MomentJS and I dont know if I have implemented it correctly and to display it in real time without refreshing the page constantly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the actual zone data.  Go to [the moment-timezone data builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) and include the zones you care about.  Put that in another file called `moment-timezone-data.js` and include it, or place it inline your existing script.  See [these docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/).

To update it in realtime, you need to update the element on a regular interval.

Also, in your example code, the first time you are calling moment with the timezone, you are throwing away the response.  The second call, you're not using the time zone.  And you don't need jQuery here.

Putting it all together:

```
function showTheTime() {
    var s = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('hh:mm:ss a');    
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = s;
}

showTheTime(); // for the first load
setInterval(showTheTime, 250); // update it periodically
```

You might think that setting the interval to 1000 ms would be ok, but you may find that it visually does not tick smoothly.  That happens because the interval timer might not align with the actual clock.  It's better to update multiple times per second.

Comment: I did all of the steps you told me to do, but it doesnt seem to work. Within my span element, do i need to invoke any particular method from the script? Currently, this is what I have. <span id="time">test</span>. By right it should just overwrite 'test' with the timezone, correct?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite whatever is in there with rendered time string.  You may need to invoke this code *after* you define your span, or if from something like  the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function if you use jQuery.

Comment: It works, thanks alot. Why is it in some cases, some javascripts dont work until after some elements that are inside the body tag?

Comment: JavaScript executes sequentially as it is encountered.  If you try to access an element before it is loaded, then it won't find it.  You can put stuff earlier if you rely on the `onLoad` event, or jQuery's `ready` event, or something like that.  But if you just run it inline, it will have to come after the element is defined.

Comment: I see Ok. Thanks again for the tips and solution.

Comment: For anyone that does not require real time seconds information, and just wants to update the display once a minute: http://jsfiddle.net/ws45S/ In this manner, the value updates in sync with the users clock, and only once per minute instead of 4 times a second.

Comment: @Matt Johnson how do I get this to work for any other timezone? it currently says  `Coming soon...` in the link you provided [the moment-timezone data builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/)

Comment: worked it out, with help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877791/how-to-load-time-zone-data-into-moment-timezone-js) `Don't load moment-timezone-with-data and then use moment.tz.add, as that just duplicates the zone information that's already in the data file` here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKUwn/147/) - had to basically add a source, remove a source and comment out the `moment.tz.add` part.

Comment: What if I want to create a timer by passing milliseconds (based on timezone)? Suppose, I'm in America/Los_Angeles timezone, I can get the milliseconds by moment().tz(timezone).valueOf(). How to create a real timer using this?

Comment: @PranjalSuccessena - `valueOf` gives the unix timestamp.  Unix timestamps are _always_ in terms of UTC.  They are not affected by time zones - by their very nature of being the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC.